# Accessing multi-level fields in a CRM 2011 Workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

Sorry if this is sort of confusing because I'm not sure how to word this.  I am trying to create a workflow that runs off of Account's in Microsoft CRM 2011.  One part of this workflow requires me to retrieve a field contained in the Business Unit of the User in the Account's "Created By" field.  However, the workflow will only allow me to access the Business Unit itself, but not any of its fields.

I'm wondering if there is a simple trick or work-around that will allow me access to this data.

Thanks!

For reference, the Account has a User, who has a Business Unit, and the Business Unit has a field I need to access.  CRM, however, doesn't want to let me get more than 2 levels deep when accessing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clunky but do-able if you accept a bit of denormalisation (temporarily or otherwise). I'll assume for the sake of example you want to get at the "cost centre" field from the BU.

Add a field on User entity to temporarily hold the value from the BU (so make it same type and length, text(100) in this case), optionally put it on the form.

Create a child workflow for the User entity to update the user with the "cost centre" value from their BU. Make it only available to run as a child, not onDemand or anything else. Activate

In your Account workflow, add a step to call the child workflow against the relevant user (eg Created By in your case).
Add a step to wait until the new cost centre field on the user record contains data.
Now do whatever you need to with the value from the user record, such as update the Account, or do some branched logic.
Whatever you do, once you have used the value, clear the field on the user record, or do this as the last step of the workflow.

Now, since Users don't change BU very often, you might actually just go ahead and keep that value on the User record permanently, and instead of a child workflow, simply run this on create of a new user, or on change of BU, and store the value permanently on the User record. Yes, it is 'denormalised' and not purest SQL design, but then you don't need a child workflow, you don't need a wait state and you don't have to clear the value at the end, or worry about what happens when two Accounts need to run their workflow at the same time. I include the more general approach above as this might apply to other records which do change their parent quite often.

Just an additional thought - you can access the "owning business unit" of the Account, but this will be the BU of the Owning User, rather than the Created By, but is your business process such that this would normally be the same person? (eg users only have Create priviledge to "user owned" depth, so can only create records they own).
If so, then you could get at the BU directly from the Account, and then any fields on it too (in a condition or to update the Account)

Alternative which is less ideal but a similar approach - add a relationship from Account to BU (eg "created BU"). Now you can update the Account with this by referring to the Created By User's BU, then in the next step, reference this value from the Account. This is again denormalised, and less preferable since number of Accounts is far greater than number of users, so the level of duplicate information is much higher.

Comment: you want to lead him to the `Dark side` of denormalisation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't get deeper with the standard steps of a workflow.

The solution is to create a custom workflow activity, you can start from this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx